# Can I include IE conditional comments inside an opening tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Basically, I'd like to know if this code is okay,

```
<body id="some_id" <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>class="ie6"<![endif]--> >
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. HTML comments can't be inside a tag. Try:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>--> <body id="some_id"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <body id="some_id" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks, my trouble is that the body may or may not have an id depending on a server side script, looks like I'll have to find another solution

Comment: @mjr why not let the server side script handle it then?

Comment: ya ... I'm not familiar with browser sniffing on the server side

Comment: Why would the fact may or may not have an id, influence on whether or not you can use Conditional Comments?

Comment: @Jean Paul: You are right, there is a syntax error. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2):

No, and it's not necessary. Always give the class to the body element and leave the CSS `.ie` definition empty for all browsers but IE6:

```
.ie6 {
<!--[if lt IE 7]-->
    ... ugly ie6 hack ...
<!--[endif]-->
}
</style>
<body class="ie6">
```

Comment: good thought, but that limits me to one version of ie in the class

If I wanted to add and ie7 or ie8 class in the future, I don't know if this would be the best solution

Comment: Why? You can add as many classes to a single element as you need (separate them by space) or you could use `ie` as the generic class and then put a lot of `if`s inside of the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No — comments cannot be inserted inside tags.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, so you will have to repeat the tag and all its attributes.

A lot of people add the browser identifier class in the `<html>` tag. Using the `body` tag is also fine but I would use whichever tag has the least amount of characters in its attributes.

A wordpress 'body' tag may looks like this

`<body class="home page page-id-38 page-template page-template-template-homepage page-template-template-homepage-php woocommerce-demo-store storefront-full-width-content right-sidebar woocommerce-active has-site-logo">`

So you would put the class in the `<html>` tag so save repeating that long string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    </head>
    <body class="home page page-id-38 page-template page-template-template-homepage page-template-template-homepage-php woocommerce-demo-store storefront-full-width-content right-sidebar woocommerce-active has-site-logo">
```

A `html` tag may look like this.

`<html class="" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Webpage">`

In this case you might put the class in the `<body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Webpage">
    <head>
    </head>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <body class="ie6"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

If I had something which left me not optio but to repeat a huge string multiple times, like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Webpage">
<head>
</head>
<body class="home page page-id-38 page-template page-template-template-homepage page-template-template-homepage-php woocommerce-demo-store storefront-full-width-content right-sidebar woocommerce-active has-site-logo">
```

Then I would probably use javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Webpage">
<head>
<script>
    (function(){
        var d=document,
            h=d.documentElement,
            v = 3,
            p = d.createElement('p'),
            i = p.getElementsByTagName('i'),
            u;
            while (
                p.innerHTML =  '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
                i[0]
            );
            h.className += (v > 4 ? ' ie'+v : '');
    })()
</script>
</head>
<body class="home page page-id-38 page-template page-template-template-homepage page-template-template-homepage-php woocommerce-demo-store storefront-full-width-content right-sidebar woocommerce-active has-site-logo">
```

This script is a modifed version of [James Padolsey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228216/2273611) script, which adds the class to the `html` tag.