# How to detect if i can use jquery on a browser or not

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I currently using jquery in my website but when i try to open this website on ie 5.5 i get the error "$" is undefined so i am searching for a solution to detect if the browser support jquery or not before calling any jquery code

Comment: why are you supporting ie 5.5?!?!

Comment: here is the list of compatibility. http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @DanielA.White: I think he wants to check it at runtime so that he prevents the error.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Does the *why* matter? Sometimes, I still support IE5.5 - but I charge an arm and a leg for that, on top of the IE6 support fees (to dissuade the clients, mainly, and then to cover the development costs). Even so, some clients are still willing to pay for IE5.5 support.

Comment: ignore 5.5 ... you can also ignore IE 6 becouse it is not recommended to use it anymore (by Microsoft!!) if you take a look at browser statistics IE 6 is used by like 1-5% of all IE users. Its ok to ignore it. 5.5 is not even in the statstics anymore !! that why!

Comment: @Piskvor I would never take a project where I was asked to support IE 6 or below. Sorry, it's just not worth it IMHO.

Comment: @Yuck: I would never take it at normal rates, either ;) It's a challenge, really - "can you make it work with IE5 and NN 4.78?"

Comment: @SamirAdel: You may want to check out [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4228216/376743) that shows a clever use of conditional comments as a non-spoofable way of detecting the version of IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {alert('no jquery');}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have answered your own question. Check if `$` is undefined. Thoguh as mentioned in the comments, IE 5.5 is not supported.

**Edit**

In case you needed the code to check if the alias for jQuery is undefined:

```
typeof $ == 'undefined'
```

Comment: That's going to read wrong on Prototype (which also uses `$`). Checking for `jQuery` is more foolproof.

Comment: @Piskvor that is why I stated that this would check the `$` alias.