# JavaScript left and right click function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is for an HTML5 canvas game that I am making.  In the game, there is a character that has a gun, he can shoot it and reload it.  I would like the player to use the left mouse button for shooting and the right mouse button for reloading.

What I need is that when ever I click the left mouse button, a variable in my player object(Player1.isLeftClick) becomes true, and when I let go of the button the same variable becomes false.  The same thing should also happen with the right mouse button, but with another variable(Player1.isRightClick).  I also want it to be capable with all the most popular browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Explorer, etc.).  **I must also be in pure JavaScript with no libraries like jQuery!**
I already achieved this with keyboard events, but I need this with the mouse events.

If it helps, I already have event handlers for keyboard up and down and mouse movement.  These are made in the init function that initializes the game when the images are loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousePos, false);
document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp, false);
```

I also have variable called mie that is true if the used browser is Internet Explorer and false for other browsers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use the [`e.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.button) property to check which mouse event was called. The value for the left mouse button being clicked is [different in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button). Your code would look like this:

```
var left, right;
left = mie ? 1 : 0;
right = 2;

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e){
    if(e.button === left){
        Player1.isLeftClick = true;
    }
    else if(e.button === right){
        Player1.isRightClick = true;
    }
}, false);

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e){
    if(e.button === left){
        Player1.isLeftClick = false;
    }
    else if(e.button === right){
        Player1.isRightClick = false;
    }
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HBbj4/)

Comment: jsfiddle: Uncaught ReferenceError: mie is not defined

Comment: @Kroid, yeah. You need to populate it via your favourite IE detection way. Check out [some of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169160/javascript-ie-detection-why-not-use-simple-conditional-comments)

Comment: You can simplify the code by only checking if the button is right (2).  If it's not right, then it's the left button.

Comment: @SingleStepper That's not true - mice commonly also have a clickable scroll button (and occasionally others too, for gaming mice). You ought to test for equality for conditions instead of testing for inequality and inferring it.