# Drag Drop Download which supports IE Javascript/Jquery/Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried the availabe **drag drop download** samples but the problem is it works perfectly fine in Chrome but when you try to drag drop a file onto the local machine with the intention of downloading using IE, it only downloads a shortcut link to the file.

Anyone have a solution to the problem ?? please share...

I tried to work with the code in the following link.
http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="author" content="The CSS Ninja">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Drag and drop, HTML5, DownloadURL, setData, dataTransfer">
 <meta name="description" content="How to create reverse drag and drop functionality like Gmail in Chrome 5 and upwards">
 <meta name="robots" content="all">
 <meta name="copyright" content="The CSS Ninja">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_styles.css" media="screen">
 
 <title>Drag a file from a website to your filesystem like Gmail does | The CSS Ninja</title>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Drag out any of these links to your dekstop</h1>
  
  <a href="Eadui.ttf" id="dragout" class="dragme" draggable="true" data-downloadurl="application/octet-stream:Eadui2.ttf:http://thecssninja.come/demo/gmail_dragout/Eadui.ttf">Font file</a>
  
  <a href="Eadui.ttf" id="dragout2" class="dragme" draggable="true" data-downloadurl="application/pdf:HTML5CheatSheet.pdf:http://thecssninja.come/demo/gmail_dragout/html5-cheat-sheet.pdf">PDF file</a>
 </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var files = [document.getElementById("dragout"),document.getElementById("dragout2"),document.getElementById("dragout3")],
   fileDetails = [];
  
  // Some forward thinking, utilise the custom data attribute to extend attributes available.
  if(typeof files[0].dataset === "undefined") {
   // Grab it the old way
   fileDetails[0] = files[0].getAttribute("data-downloadurl");
   fileDetails[1] = files[1].getAttribute("data-downloadurl");
  } else {
   fileDetails[0] = files[0].dataset.downloadurl;
   fileDetails[1] = files[1].dataset.downloadurl;
  }
  
  files[0].addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt){
   evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",fileDetails[0]);
  },false);
  files[1].addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt){
   evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",fileDetails[1]);
  },false);
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: Please refer the original qestion where I modified it with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari and Microsoft Edge.

Why work on an older browser that [Microsoft no longer supports](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)?

My suggestion would be because it's no longer supported tell your users to use a [supported browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845268/if-other-than-ie-show-alert-html-js).

Comment: The main intention of the solution is to add the functionality into a SharePoint site which runs on IE... Therefore, Chrome and FF would not fit in.

Comment: You never said that. You said, "I tried to work with the code" from [this](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout) resource. I'm not familiar with SharePoint, but I do know it's a Microsoft product and supports Edge. [Microsoft no longer supports IE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) so it's pointless to code for it. Saves the headache.